# Selenium automation for graphs

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to automate a graph which shows different values in tooltip when you hover over different points (graph locations). I tried to get the xpath of these locations and they all show the same xpath. something like ".//*[@id='chart']/svg/path"  Can you please let me know 1) how to automate to hover over the specified location of graph using selenium and then 2) get the tooltip values. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Find all elements of the graph, then iterate over them and find the one you need:

```java
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='chart']/svg/path"));
```

#### Option 2

Clarify the xpath, for example by specifying an attribute:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='chart']/svg/path[@fill='#ffee44']"));
```

(note that this locator most likely will not work for you. Share the graph you're working with if you need an accurate answer)